# Matplotlib Table Y-axis Alignment to Chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've seen plenty of examples online of x-axis alignment for matplotlib Table with charts, but I can't figure out how to y-axis align my table. The following code produces the table pictured after it.

```
# For minimum viable example

dfx = [['ARS FX', 0.025346713729, 0.028238, 0.021889, 0.07701426, 0.0, 35, 39, '14.7%', 0.0, 0.07701426], ['BRL FX',1.83316130513e-05,0.025746,-0.072473, 0.143642325, 0.0, 40, 45, '12.3%', 0.0, 0.143642325], ['EUR FX', -0.301254060209, -0.300762, -0.290554, 0.0, -0.30127866, -60, -40, '5.2%', -0.30127866, 0.0], ['ZAR FX', 0.0515621470331, 0.053191, 0.044245, 0.07344438, 0.0, 10, 29, '14.1%', 0.0, 0.07344438], ['AR Eqity', 3.68762762118e-06, 0.0,0.0, 0.08817912, 0.0, 45, 45, '23.9%', 0.0, 0.08817912]]

dfx = pd.DataFrame(dfx)
dfx.columns = ['IdeaName', 'ModelWeight', 'Exposure_FXA', 'Exposure','Adj_Ubound', 'Adj_Lbound', 'lt_rob', 'st_rob', 'implied_vol', 'Lower Bound', 'Upper Bound']

# Plot
_, ax = plt.subplots()

dfx[['Lower Bound']].plot(kind='barh',ax=ax,color='red')
dfx[['Upper Bound']].plot(kind='barh',ax=ax,color='green')

plt.plot(dfx['ModelWeight'],range(len(dfx)), linestyle="", markersize=5, marker="o", color="#ff6600", label="ModelWeight", markeredgecolor="k")
plt.plot(dfx['Exposure'],range(len(dfx)), linestyle="", markersize=5, marker="o", color='lightblue', label="Exposure", markeredgecolor="k")

# Add a table at the bottom of the axes
columns = ['LT','ST','Vol']
the_table = ax.table(cellText=dfx[['lt_rob','st_rob','implied_vol']].values,
                      rowLabels=list(dfx['IdeaName']),
                      # rowColours=colors,
                      colWidths=[0.1 for x in columns],
                      colLabels=columns,
                      cellLoc='center',
                      loc=15)

the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(9)
the_table.scale(1, 1.05)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.4)

plt.yticks([])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, despite me manually playing with `the_table.scale()` to get it as close as possible, I can't get the rows aligned with my bars, since the column headers of the table are taking up the first row.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to provide a [mcve], I can adapt it, such that it aligns properly.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a portion that gives you the first couple rows of the data I'm using.

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: just fixed, thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Refer to the answer how a minimal example should look like... noone cares about any actual data and unrelated content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would put the table into a bounding box that is one nth larger than the number of bars n. One then needs to make sure the margins within the axes are correct as well as the subplot parameter. The below only adjusts the vertical direction (the horizontal direction needs to be done by hand for longer labels).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.randint(1,999,size=(10,4))
col = list("ABCD")
row = np.arange(1, len(data)+1)

n = len(data)   # number of bars
barwidth = 0.8  # bar width
t = 0.05
b = 0.125

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.4, top=1-t-(1-t-b)/(n+1))

ax.margins(y=(1-barwidth)/2/n)

ax.barh(row, data[:,0], height=barwidth, label="bars", )

the_table = ax.table(cellText=data,
                      rowLabels=row,
                      colLabels=col,
                      cellLoc='center',
                      bbox=(-0.6, 0.0, 0.6, (n+1) / n))

the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(9)
fig.canvas.draw()   # need to draw the figure twice

plt.yticks([])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Copy and pasting your example, I get something different from your picture. Sure enough, the table lines up perfectly to the chart, but the table header is still within the chart's y-axis, unsure why this would be. I'm on python 2.7.13, matplotlib 2.0.2

Comment: Experimenting, and in bbox, when I use (n+0.99) instead of (n+1), it works perfectly...thanks for the answer!

Comment: python 2 does integer division differently. Use `(n+1.0)`